# Kurento Media Server Error

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I am using the same PC / Laptop and same server to test Kurento Media Server:

```
Version: 5.1.3
Found modules:
        Module: 'core' version '5.1.5'
        Module: 'elements' version '5.1.4'
        Module: 'filters' version '5.1.1'
```

I sometimes get the following error:

```
2015-07-08 22:44:31.860340 9559 [140269295921280]   error KurentoMediaPipelineImpl  MediaPipelineImpl.cpp:71 busMessage() Error on bus: error message: 0x7f92e01eec30, time 99:99:99.999999999, seq-num 422016, element 'dtlsdec42', GstMessageError, gerror=(GError)NULL, debug=(string)"/build/kms-elements-rKurus/kms-elements-5.1.4/src/gst-plugins/dtls-plugins/gstdtlsdec.c\(227\):\ gst_dtls_dec_loop\ \(\):\ /GstPipeline:pipeline15/KmsWebrtcEndpoint:kmswebrtcendpoint45/GstDtlsSrtpDec:dtlssrtpdec42/GstDtlsDec:dtlsdec42:\012Error\ decrypting\ DTLS\ stream:\ Error\ reading\ data\ from\ TLS\ socket:\ The\ operation\ timed\ out";
```

Sometimes I can connect and get WebRTC video successfully, sometimes when I get a black blank screen on my video tag, the error above appears.

Not sure what could have happened? and how to fix it?

Comment: You should migrate to KMS v6.x. Version 5 is not longer supported and it has well known bugs that wont fix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable DTLS-SRTP
Example with chrome:

```
if (chrome) {
    new RTCPeerConnection(ICE_Servers, {
        optional: [{
                DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement: true
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: You mean pass the DTLS_SRTP in getUserMedia function?

Comment: Updated solution, please check above

Comment: I have added and let it run for a while, and sometimes I still get the error as described in my question. Could unstable network connection also be a cause for the error described?